# UITextview scrollable but not editable programmly

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I make a UITextView scrollable but not editable programmly??

I tried this:

```
textmessage.enabled = NO;
textmessage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

...but doesn't work...

Comment: why don't you use `UIScrollView` then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By just setting the `editable` property of [**`UITextView`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) to `NO` you should have its content not modifiable by the user (by the way a user could still select/copy/paste the text into it).

```
[myTextView setEditable:NO];
```

If you appear to have it not scrollable may it be the case you do not have enough text inside of it?

Or maybe you can have the UITextView's property scrollEnabled disabled for some reason.

```
myTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: no, I do, even because if I do this textmessage.userInteractionEnabled = YES; it scrolls, but edits as well

Comment: `textmessage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` shall not be required. Could you please post the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: Have you set `myTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
textmessage.isEditable = false

textmessage.isScrollEnabled = true
```